# Library Project

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a pro and free version riding on my library project. The pro and free versions do not have any code. Just some alternate resources. 
Now I want to include some activities in pro. So from my library code how do I invoke these new pro activities? The control starts in Library code so I never have any opportunity to set up listeners and such from pro.
Is it a good idea to pass the absolute class name of these new activities as a string to an intent in the library project.
This maybe a noob question but I did a lot of searching. I just need a small hint.

Comment: It does not sound like a "library" project, given that control starts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I managed to solve this by using the Configuration activity of the widget. I specified a overriden xml file in manifest for the widget metadata in the main project. This overridden xml which is residing in the pro project had a pointer (android:configure)to an activity which is only residing in the main project.

With this I was able to implement licensing. In the pro version the configuration activity takes care of licensing. In the free version there is no configuration activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is opposite of what you are trying to do. Library projects should have common, shared code. If you have a pro/free version of an app, you should probably have 3 projects:

1. ProVersion project
2. FreeVersion project
3. Shared Library project

Since your alternate resources are not shared, they would each go into their own project (pro/free). Any code that's shared, will go in the library project. With this setup, any code you have in Shared Library project, you can use as if they are part of the main project.

You can think of it as having a "include", that's basically what library project is.

Comment: I have the three projects as you say. My library code is also containing shared code only. However thats all the code there is. Its a widget actually with its associated service in the library. The widget and service are in the library and common across pro and free except for some resource differences. Now from the library service I want to invoke some new component in the pro version. The problem is with the widget the control starts from there in the library code. thanks for your reply.